# How to install jboss7.1 on centos7?

Tags: linux, centos, java, jboss

I have used following commands to install java.

```
 wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u112-b15/jdk-8u112-linux-x64.rpm"
```

After that  `yum install jdk-8u112-linux-x64.rpm`

Now i downloaded the jboss

```
wget http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip
```

after that unziped it

```
unzip jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip
I have placed jboss in /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final directory
```

after that i have used following commands

```
 adduser jboss
 chown -fR jboss.jboss /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/
 su jboss
```

also i saved that path using the command

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Actually i am following these steps from a tutorial and in the last when i am running the `standalone.sh` file its showing following lines and not moving beyond this, please help
its is not moving beyond this

```
    [jboss@centos_pc2 bin]$ ./standalone.sh 
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss-as

  JAVA: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112//bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
12:47:33,368 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
12:47:33,608 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
12:47:33,679 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Comment: is it stuck on "JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting" ??

Comment: yup@AliGolestan

Comment: please check this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493514/jboss-not-starting-without-error"     and i think issue is in java 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to change to Java version 7 or 6 and then try to start JBoss again.

Comment: [root@centos_pc2 ~]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Try java version 1.7 or 1.6

Comment: please tell how to change java version from 1.8 to 1.7. When i am installing java 1.7, it replying that latest  version of 1.7 has already been installed.

Comment: Try downloading and installing the specific version from Java downloads, then change the Java home path